# Entity Framework 5 HasRequired not works

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I have 2 tables

USERS

```
[Id] INT NOT NULL PK IDENTITY,
[FirstName] nvarchar, 
[LastName] nvarchar

and ACCOUNTS
[Id] INT NOT NULL PK,
[Password] nvarchar,
CONSTRAINT FK_Accounts_Users FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES [security].[Users] (Id)
```

I need to add at the same time Users and it's Profile.

Using EF FulentApi I make such models:

```
public UserConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Users", "Security");
            HasKey(i => i.Id);
            Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            Property(i => i.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
            Property(i => i.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");

            HasRequired(i => i.Account).WithRequiredPrincipal(i => i.User);
}

public AccountConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Accounts", "Security");
            HasKey(i => i.Id);
            Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
            Property(i => i.Password).HasColumnName("Password");

            HasRequired(i => i.User).WithRequiredDependent();
}
```

Then, when I add User with Account it allows me to add null Acount, i.e. this code will works

```
using(var db = new SecurityDbContext())
            {
                var user = db.Users.Add(new User
                                            {
                                                FirstName = "John",
                                                LastName = "Rambo"
                                            });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Why Account is null, if in my UserConfiguration model I set Account as required?

And how then I can make a relationship User to Account 1:1?

Thanks in advance.